# How to add object to array in the other class, Java

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-studio

How to add object to array in an other class?
This is my code:

```
public class One
{
   //Loots is a class  
   public static Loots[] lootsList = new Loots[] { };
}   
 
public class Two
{ 
   Loots MyLoots = new Loots();         
   // How to add MyLoots to lootsList in THIS class? 
}
```

*I don't want to use List*

Comment: Use `List` or `ArrayList` instead. Much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing Static variable and method of another class

```
ClassName.StaticVariable;
```

**OR**

```
ClassName.StaticMethod;
```

**NOTE:- Static variable and Method are active in whole Application.**

use this

```
public class One
    {
       public static Loots[] lootsList = new Loots[1];
    }   

    public class Two
    { 
       Loots MyLoots = new Loots();         
       // How to add in THIS class, MyLoots to lootsList? 
       One.Loots[0]=MyLoots; //use this to access array of objects
    }
```

enjoy coding .........

Answer (score 1):

```
public class One{
   public List<Loots> lootsList = new ArrayList<Loots>();

   public void someVoid(){
       new Two(this);
   }
}   

public class Two
{ 
    One one;
    public Two(One one){
        this.one = one:
    }

   Loots MyLoots = new Loots();         
   // How to add in THIS class, MyLoots to lootsList? 

    public void someVoid(){
        one.lootsList.add(MyLoots);
    }

}
```

This is a better way to do it because the ArrayList can hold as many objects as you need without it being defined by the initialization of the list.

BY defining it like you did, there has to be a specific amount of Loots max in the array.

Alternative:

```
public static Loots[] lootsList = new Loots[20];
```

Example:

```
public class One{

    public static Loots[] lootsList = new Loots[20];
    public void someVoid(){
       new Two(this);
    }
}   

public class Two
{ 
    One one;
    public Two(One one){
        this.one = one:
    }

   Loots MyLoots = new Loots();         
   // How to add in THIS class, MyLoots to lootsList? 

    public void someVoid(){
        one.lootsList[0].add(MyLoots);
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't want to using List.

Comment: If you don't want to use arraylist you have to define the amount of Loots max in the array